# Why does a ruby parent class assume class variables of its children?

Tags: ruby

Given this code:

```
class Mammal
  @@class_name = "mammal"
  def self.class_name
    @@class_name
  end
end

class Dog < Mammal
  @@class_name = "dog"
  def self.class_name
    @@class_name
  end
end

Dog.class_name
# => dog
Mammal.class_name
# => dog
```

Why is this a feature of ruby? Seems like class variables follow a different scope than instance variables do for instances. Is a class variable's scope shared across its entire inheritance chain? If so, why is that? They are separate classes and should have scoped class variables, no? What am I missing?

Comment: Hello.  You've asked a couple of related questions.  One of those questions is an exact duplicate, which is why I just applied the so-called "dup hammer."  The other, "why," is not an exact duplicate, although I suspect it's a tough question to find an answer for.  For the most part, the answer is "that's the way it is, because the author of Ruby decided to make it so."  If we were lucky enough to find something that Matz wrote about class variable behavior, then the "why" part could be answerable.

Comment: Class variables are not only shared between a class and its subclasses, but also between a class and its instances.

Comment: I should also add that `@@` class variables are almost never a good idea.  Whenever I've worked with code that used them, I'm usually able to change them to class instance variables, which are easier to reason about.

Comment: thanks @WayneConrad sorry for the duplicate, this makes sense

Comment: from the horses mouth https://twitter.com/yukihiro_matz/status/791300638592241664 : "consider these as global variables with limited scope."

Answer (score 0):

Class variables are shared throughout the class hierarchy, they are not inherited, so assignment order matters:

```
class Mammal
  @@class_name = "mammal"
  def self.class_name
    @@class_name
  end
end

class Dog < Mammal
  @@class_name = "dog"
  def self.class_name
    @@class_name
  end
end

class Mammal
  @@class_name = "fish"
end

Dog.class_name # fish
Mammal.class_name # fish
```

**UPDATE**

Use class instance variables instead, class variables are tricky:

```
class Mammal
  @class_name = "mammal"
  def self.class_name
    @class_name
  end
end

class Dog < Mammal
  @class_name = "dog"
  def self.class_name
    @class_name
  end
end

Dog.class_name # dog
Mammal.class_name # mammal
```

Comment: why are class variables shared throughout class hierarchy? why don't they have class scope?

Comment: @AndrewKim Because it's how class variables work

Comment: any ideas why thats a feature? Seems like class instance variables could have conflicts with actual object instance variables

Comment: thanks either way, this has given me a lot more clarity!

Comment: @Andrew Kim. No they can't have clashes, because **instance variables** are bound to `self` which is the _current object_ running at that time

Comment: Andrew, a class instance variable `@cat` and an instance variable `@cat` are as different as `@night` and `@day`.